# How to decrease size the EBS root volume of the RHEL instance in AWS?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redhat-enterprise-linux

Created an RHEL instance with an root EBS volume of 200GB. Currently it uses only 10% of the available volume. How to decrease the size of the EBS volume in AWS?

I followed the below mentioned steps to decrease the root volume size.

> 1.Stopped the instance
>
> 2.Dettached the root volume from the instance
>
> 3.Attached the root volume to an another instance which is running
>
> 4.Created a new volume with the required size. (Lets say 50GB)
>
> 5.Attached the new volume to the running instance
>
> 6.Copied all the data from the old volume to the new volume
>
> 7.Detached the new volume and attached to the stopped instance.
>
> 8.Created the AMI for the old instance.
>
> 9.Relaunched the instance from the AMI The instance is showing starting
>   and after some time it is automatically shutting down.

PFB the executed commands

```
sudo mkdir /new /old    create new directories
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdf    create new filesystem on new volume
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/xvdf /new   mount it to this directory
sudo e2label /dev/xvdf uec-rootfs   needs an e2label for linux to recognize it, use sudo e2label /dev/sda1 on an active instant to see what it should be
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/xvdg /old   mount old vol to directory for copying
sudo cp -p /old /new    didn’t really do anything.. Skipped a bunch
sudo rsync -ax /old /new    took a while
sudo mv /new/old/* /new/
sudo umount /new    unmount vols
sudo umount /old
```

Kindly help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Decrease is far, far more difficult to explain than increase.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thats why i asked this question here :P

Comment: Can you not just snapshot the volume, create a new volume with your desired size based on that snapshot?

Comment: @Tim From snapshot you can increase the size but you cannot decrease the size